# Using Farm_fingerprint for Google Big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have tables I am importing into Google Big Query.
These tables are my staging tables and I am using Views to transform the staging tables into a logical warehouse table.
My issue is surrogate keys.

Right now, ROW_NUMBER() is failing because my data is too large.

I have been recommended to use FARM_FINGERPRINT

Is there a proper way to employ Surrogate_key Generation in Big Query?

Thanks

## UPDATE 1 for clarification.

Some of my source tables have 30 fields with millions of records.  To big to display here.  We are transforming those records into tables with the need to create surrogate keys to assist with BI tools later on.

To that end, our views (to replace target tables with) have the transformations, plus we were using ROW_NUMBER() functions to create unique surrogate keys.  We realized that the function forces Big Query to push the entire logic onto one node, which crashes the query.

We are playing around with FARM_FINGERPRINT(), using a string of concatenated fields that represent a unique business key as an input to retrieve a INT64 value to use as a surrogate key.  The belief is that this will provide an integer that we can use in the BI tools as needed by that team.

what I am asking is there is a proper way to generate an integer-based surrogate key in Google Big Query when you have such a large dataset?

Thanks.

Comment: if you can provide more specific example it will be easier (and better for you) to answer. now it is too generic!

Comment: To clarify--is the intention to have a column alongside your table with unique keys? What is the schema of your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you find a different strategy to partition your data?

This fails with "resources exceeded" (as expected - note that I'm not trying to de-duplicate them, but to number each of their mentions):

```
SELECT author
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY created_utc)
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_06`
```

But I could partition my authors by the first letter, to have the data fit in a partition:

```
SELECT author
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REGEXP_EXTRACT(author, '.') ORDER BY created_utc)
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_06`
```

This works! Now each row can have an id composed of `first_letter_author`+`row_number`:

```
SELECT *
  , CONCAT(
      first_letter
      , '-'
      , CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER(PARTITION BY REGEXP_EXTRACT(author, '.') 
      ORDER BY created_utc) AS STRING)) id
FROM (
  SELECT author, created_utc, REGEXP_EXTRACT(author, r'^.') first_letter
  FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_06`
)
```

Comment: Hi Felipe....thank you so much for the idea.  We tossed that one around for a bit, and we were told by our Business Intelligence Operators that the inclusion of letters into the SK converts the field from an Integer to a String.  In their systems String Comparison is a no go.  Love the idea tho.  Thanks!

Comment: The same strategy will work with integers. Instead of doing strings, use a HASH() or whatever number helps you partition the data in rows that then you can `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY )`